# Diferenciar el remitente de un mensaje de otro

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Estoy haciendo un bot para discord usando discord.js y me ha surgido una duda:

Yo tengo un client.on en el que si se usa por ejemplo el comando s!ruta1, nos manda un embed que nos pide el comando s!catch para volver a mandarnos otro mensaje distinto. El problema viene que una vez mandado el primer embed, cualquiera puede mandar el comando s!catch para que les envie el siguiente mensaje. La pregunta es: ¿Cómo hago para que el bot sólo envíe el segundo mensaje cuando el usuario que mandó primero el comando s!ruta1 use el comando s!catch?

Aquí el código:

```
const Ruta1 = [lista.WildPokemon.Pidgey, lista.WildPokemon.Rattata]

function random_item(sitio)
    {
      return sitio[Math.floor(Math.random()*sitio.length)];
    }

client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    lugar=["ruta1","ruta2","ruta3"];
    for(i = 0; i < lugar.length; i++){
    if(message.content == prefix + lugar[i]){
    switch(lugar[i]){
      case "ruta1": var appearedpokemon = random_item(Ruta1); break;
    }
      const filter = m => m.content.includes('s!catch');
      const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({filter,  time: 15000 });
    
      const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    
      .setAuthor({ name: `${message.author.username}`, iconURL: `${message.author.avatarURL()}`})
      .setTitle(`¡Un ${appearedpokemon.Name} salvaje apareció!\n(s!catch para capturar, límite: 20 segundos)\n`)
      .setImage(`${appearedpokemon.Image}`)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter({ text: 'El Sicario'});
    
      message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
    
      collector.on('collect', m => { 
        message.channel.send(`¡**${message.author.username}**, has capturado un ${appearedpokemon.Name}!`)
        let pokemon = db.fetch(`pokemonlist_${message.author.id}`)
        db.add(`Puntoslist_${message.author.id}`, 3)
        
        if(pokemon===null||!pokemon.includes(appearedpokemon.Name)) {
        db.push(`pokemonlist_${message.author.id}`, appearedpokemon.Name)
        db.add(`pokemon_${message.author.id}`, 1)
        message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, ${appearedpokemon.Name} se ha registrado en tu Pokédex.`)
       } 
       collector.stop()
      });
    
    }}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrias modificar el filtro que aplicas a tu collector, comprobando si el id del autor del mensaje `s!catch` es el mismo que el del autor de `s!ruta1`

```js
const filter = m => m.content.includes('s!catch') && m.author.id === message.author.id;
```

Espero haberte ayudado.